# onMessageReceived is never invoked

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I upgraded my firebase dependencies. However I do not receive push notifications anymore as onMessageReceived is never called be it in foreground or background

My gradle dependencies for firebase:

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:18.0.0"
```

My manifest:

```
<service android:name=".TestService">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
     </intent-filter>
</service>
```

My service:

```
public class TestService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
private static final String TAG = makeLogTag(TestService.class);

@Override
public void onNewToken(String refreshedToken) {
    super.onNewToken(refreshedToken);
    LOGE(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
}

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();

    LOGE(TAG, "Received FCM message from : " + remoteMessage.getFrom() + " 
     data : " + data);
     }
 }
```

Comment: check, firebase is configured with your project, google-services.json file.

Comment: @NavinKumar I checked the file...No changes there

Comment: implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'  try this

Comment: @NavinKumar I tried it and I have this error: Failed to notify project evaluation listener.